# A Recommendation Engine With Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an app that recommends university courses based on your high school marks and I am using **Firebase** as the backend, I am trying to figure out if its possible to create a recommendations engine using **Firebase** and **Google Cloud Functions**?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you be more specific? Currently this question can be seen as too broad. Also take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, Firebase can do this. Not sure how to else to answer as it's a very broad question with no details and it's not really a specific coding question.